# Function in Oracle to Get time along with a Display Message :)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Hey I tried It for a lot of time but I cannot fix this simple program to work for my personal website.I want to extract the current time and display a message with it.

Like The current time is: 12:00 am

Here is my code.

```
Create Function A1SF_GETTIME Is

    Temptime Char(20);   
    Message  Varchar2(20) := 'The Current Time is :';
    Begin
    Select to_char(sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS') As "Current Time"   
    Into   TempTime   
    From dual;
    dbms_output.put_line(Message || ' ' || TempTime);      
End;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function needs to have a `RETURN` clause in the function definition.  And it has to have a `RETURN` statement so that the function actually returns something.  If you fix that, along with the fact that others have pointed out that your local variable `Message` is too small, you could do something like this

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  Create or replace Function A1SF_GETTIME
  2    return varchar2
  3  Is
  4    l_time    varchar2(10) := to_char( sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS' );
  5    l_message Varchar2(30) := 'The Current Time is : ' || l_time;
  6  Begin
  7    dbms_output.put_line( l_message );
  8    return l_message;
  9* End;
SQL> /

Function created.

SQL> select a1sf_gettime from dual;

A1SF_GETTIME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Current Time is : 14:09:47
```

Comment: Loved your answer as It also returned a Message which will be very useful when I start this in Asp.net or Vb

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
to_char(sysdate, '"The current time is "hh24:mi:ss')
```

as in

```
SQL> select to_char(sysdate, '"The current time is "hh24:mi:ss') from dual;

TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'"THECURRENT
----------------------------
The current time is 09:16:08
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the error is since you haven't shown it :-) but you can greatly simplify your code with something like:

```
create function A1SF_GETTIME is
    Temptime Char(50);
begin
    select 'The current time is ' || to_char (sysdate, 'HH24:MI:SS')
        into TempTime from dual;
    dbms_output.put_line (TempTime);
end;
```

You'll have to increase the size of the `TempTime` buffer since it holds all the data, and 50 should be big enough for the resultant string. This is offset by the fact that you can get rid of `Message` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Your code wasn't so bad... you're string buffer was simply too small for your message!

This would work:

```
    Message VARCHAR2(21)
```